# iterating over a group in multimap how do I know if I am in first or last elements?

Tags: c++, c++11, iteration, multimap

I mean this situation:

```
for (auto iter = myMmap.equal_range(find_key).first;
  iter != myMmap.equal_range(find_key).second;
  ++iter)
{
  //code
}
```

How to derive from the iterator (that is without using counters) that I'm in first or last item in this set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this?

```
auto range = myMmap.equal_range(find_key);

for (auto it = range.first; it != range.second; ++it) {
    if (it == range.first) { // first

    } else if (std::next(it) == range.second) { // last

    } else {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I trust mixing `iter` and `cit` is typo.

You check if the iterator is the first or last element in a group just like you do in the for_cycle - first element is `equal_range(find_key).first` and one element past the last one is `equal_range(find_key).second`.